# .NET Core 3.1 API POST parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I send data to server with this parameter
[image]

But get empty value in parameter of function
[image]

If i set data type `dynamic` for input function then all things is ok and i can get values.
[image]
Report Class

```
public class ColumnHistory
{
    int ECH_COUNTER { get; set; }
    int TOTAL_WEIGHT { get; set; }
    int TOTAL_COUNT { get; set; }
    string COLUMNS_PLACE { get; set; }
   
}
public class InventoryInPlace
{
  
    int ELC_SIZE { get; set; }
    int STO_COUNT { get; set; }
    int STO_WGT { get; set; }
    int STO_COUNTER { get; set; }
    string ELC_ID { get; set; }

}
public class Report
{
    public ColumnHistory[] columnHistory { get; set; }
    public InventoryInPlace[] inventoryInPlace { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Pictures of code are ***not*** a [mcve]

Comment: Please share with us the code of the `Report` class

Comment: @PeterCsala report class code added

Comment: Can you please change the parameter type to `string` to see the received payload. Or can you please capture it via `string rawRequest = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`  Please include that in the question as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not declare the access modifier,the access level for class members is `private` by default.Be sure add access modifier for properties like below:

```
public class ColumnHistory
{
    public int ECH_COUNTER { get; set; }
    public int TOTAL_WEIGHT { get; set; }
    public int TOTAL_COUNT { get; set; }
    public string COLUMNS_PLACE { get; set; }

}
public class InventoryInPlace
{

    public int ELC_SIZE { get; set; }
    public int STO_COUNT { get; set; }
    public int STO_WGT { get; set; }
    public int STO_COUNTER { get; set; }
    public string ELC_ID { get; set; }

}
```